# Jenkins Xcode-Plugin Can't Find SDK (Unit Testing)

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, ocunit

I'm using the xcode-plugin on Jenkins to run my unit tests and generate a result output in my iOS application. Although my build completes normally, when it gets to the point of executing the test portion it fails with the following error:

> Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: FunTests, sdk: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Debug, clean: NO, archive:NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: DEFAULT, codeSignIdentity: DEFAULT
>   [workspace] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target FunTests -sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/ -configuration Debug build
>   xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/" cannot be located.
>   Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
>   Archiving artifacts
>   Finished: FAILURE

Here's a screen capture of my settings:

[image: xcode-plugin config]

I've entered the correct path to the SDK, but no dice. I'm guessing this is something simple I've overlooked. Can anyone help, or even recommend an alternative way to accomplish this? I'm using Xcode 5, Jenkins v1.565, and xcode-plugin v1.4.2. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

maybe the SDK name is wrong try xcodebuild -showsdks and use the name that is shown in there